# Openerp Webkit report giving OsError

Tags: python, odoo, wkhtmltopdf

I want use webkit report engine with my openerp7, I followed the exact procedure on this site tutorial on this site http://castilloinformatica.com/wiki/index.php?title=Webkit_Report_Engine

I have installed these modules,

```
sale,
report_webkit,
base_headers_webkit,
report_webkit_chapter_server,
invoice_webkit,
sale_order_webkit
```

and added /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf  to settings

when I am trying to print the quotation order its giving following error:

```
- - [28/May/2014 13:47:47] "POST /web/dataset/call_button HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2014-05-28 13:47:47,470 1877 ERROR openerp-report-demo-data3 openerp.addons.report_webkit.webkit_report: cannot remove file /tmp/webkit.tmp.8sv0Eg.pdf: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/webkit.tmp.8sv0Eg.pdf'
2014-05-28 13:47:47,470 1877 ERROR openerp-report-demo-data3 openerp.service.web_services: Exception: [Errno 8] Exec format error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 712, in go
    (result, format) = obj.create(cr, uid, ids, datas, context)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 340, in create
    result = self.create_source_pdf(cursor, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/report/report_sxw.py", line 513, in create_source_pdf
    return self.create_single_pdf(cr, uid, ids, data, report_xml, context)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 314, in create_single_pdf
    pdf = self.generate_pdf(bin, report_xml, head, foot, htmls)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/addons/report_webkit/webkit_report.py", line 165, in generate_pdf
    status = subprocess.call(command, stderr=stderr_fd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
2014-05-28 13:47:47,622 1877 ERROR openerp-report-demo-data3 openerp.netsvc: 8
Exec format error
(<type 'exceptions.OSError'>, OSError(8, 'Exec format error'), <traceback object at 0xb3f6bdec>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 654, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 760, in exp_report_get
    return self._check_report(report_id)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 738, in _check_report
    netsvc.abort_response(exc, exc.message, 'warning', exc.traceback)
  File "/opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/netsvc.py", line 71, in abort_response
    raise openerp.osv.osv.except_osv(description, details)
except_osv: (u'8\nExec format error', (<type 'exceptions.OSError'>, OSError(8, 'Exec format error'), <traceback object at 0xb3f6bdec>))
> /opt/openerp-report/server/openerp/netsvc.py(71)abort_response()
-> raise openerp.osv.osv.except_osv(description, details)
(Pdb)
```

how can I get rid of this error

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the misleading name of the system parameter `webkit_path`. You'd imagine that this is the path / directory of wkhtmltopdf.

`webkit_path` must contain the path of the executable. In Linux this would be for example

```
/home/my_home_dir/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

In Windows it could be

```
C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe
```

depending of course on the install path of wkhtmltox.

Answer (score 0):

try to set wkhtmltopdf path in openerp (use terminal to get wkhtmltopdf path type "which wkhtmltopdf")

under the settaing->system parameter 
hope this will you